# Display data and create new data on view (Using Code first from Database Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Please everyone help me!

I used code first from database and this is Dbcontext :

```
public partial class BBDbModel : DbContext
{
    public BBDbModel()
        : base("name=BBDbModel")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Agency> Agencies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Banner_Gallery> Banner_Gallery { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Bill> Bills { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Drinks_Category> Drinks_Category { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<News> News { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<News_category> News_category { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Position> Positions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Size> Sizes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Staff> Staffs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Status_bill> Status_bill { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Details_Bill> Details_Bill { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Drinks_Size> Drinks_Size { get; set; }

    vv.vvv.......
```

And in my View:

```
@model Tuple<WebApplication3.Models.Framework.Drink, WebApplication3.Models.Framework.BBDbModel>
```

Model Item 1 is used to create new data for the "drinks" table.
Model Item 2 is used to display the data on a Dropdown.

To create a new drink I need to choose the category for it.

Now, I do not know how to display the data on the dropdown.

I am sure that BBDbModel.Drinks_Category.ToList() is the correct list of data from the database, 
I tried it on the Datagridview in Windowform

Comment: You can generate a collection of SelectListItem objects from your Drinks_Category table data inside your GET action  and pass that to the view where you will use the DropDownList/DropDownListFor helper method to generate the SELECT element. I would recommend creating & using view specific view models.

Comment: I am sure that BBDbModel.Drinks_Category.ToList() is the correct list of data from the database. I wish I could use them with @html.dropdown()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it should look like in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Drinks, 
                    ViewBag.Drinks, 
                    "Select a drink")
```

where Drinks is a List of SelectListItem which should be built something like :

```
ViewBag.Drinks = new SelectList(
    new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = "Drink1", Value = "1"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Drink2", Value = "2"},
        new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "Drink3", Value = "3"},
    }, "Value" , "Text");
```

This is just an example. There are other methods to accomplish this.

---

Since you already have a list of string ready, you could use it like :

```
@{ 
    var Drinks = new SelectList(BBDbModel.Drinks_Category.ToList()
                    .Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m, Text = m }));
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Drinks, 
                        Drinks, 
                        "Select a drink");
```

I am using a **Viewbag** here. You could include this selectlistitem in your model and avoid this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am sure that BBDbModel.Drinks_Category.ToList() is the correct list of data from the database. I wish I could use them with @html.dropdown() ?

Comment: Is `BBDbModel.Drinks_Category.ToList()` a list of string?

Comment: Yes, im sure that

Comment: You could use `BBDbModel.Drinks_Category.ToList().Select(m =>
                new SelectListItem { Value = m, Text = m });` since Dropdownlist does not like anything other than a `List<SelectListItem>`

Comment: Where should you add the lines you just added? I try : `@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Item1.Id_category, Model.Item2.Drinks_Category.ToList().Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.Id_category, Text = m.Name_category }), "Select ID")` , But it does not work.

Comment: is it working now?

Comment: :( Erorr `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.`

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 and MSSQL 2014, can I send the project to you? Plese help me, the project is small but important

Comment: Sure... Let me see if I could help:)

Comment: I have fixed it. I'm very happy. Thank you very much! :))

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying these lines, it's working LOL;

```
<div class="form-group">
    @{  
      WebApplication3.Models.Framework.BBDbModel context = new WebApplication3.Models.Framework.BBDbModel();
      var Drinks = new SelectList(context.Drinks_Category.Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.Id_category.ToString(), Text = m.Name_category.ToString() }) "Value" , "Text");
     }
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Id_category, Drinks, "Select a category drink")
</div>
```